# Why does the following code cause a "parse error (possibly incorrent indentation or mismatched brackets) at the next line of code

Tags: haskell, parse-error

I'm attempting to create a replace function and the code below creates the error described in the post title in the first line of non-commented code following it. I have no idea as to why this is happening, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 replace [] t r n = []
    replace [] _ _ _ = []
    replace xs _ _ 0 = xs
    replace (x:xs) t r n
         | x == t = r:(replace [xs] t r (n-1))
         | otherwise x (replace [xs] t r n)
```

Comment: Let all `replace`s start at the same column. So unindent the lines after the first one.

Comment: The second case is redundant, as `_` won't match anything that `t`, `r`, and `n` didn't already match. (Though it might more accurate to say the first case is redundant, as it won't match anything the second case wouldn't.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems here: all the parts of the definition should start at the same column, so you should unindent the lines after the first one. Furthermore you need to write a `=` after the `otherwise`. `xs` is a list, so you call `replace` with `replace xs`, not `replace [xs]`. For the last guard you are constructing a list, so `x : (…)`, not `x (…)`. The second clause also does not make much sense, since that is equivalent to the first one.

You thus can implement this as:

```
replace :: (Integral n, Eq a) => [a] -> a -> a -> n -> [a]
replace [] _ _ _ = []
replace xs _ _ 0 = xs
replace (x:xs) t r n
  | x == t = r : replace xs t r (n-1)
  | otherwise = x : replace xs t r n
```